# SQL query to search for any data in the database beginning with a certain 2 letters

Tags: sql

Does anybody know how to create a query to search a table for any entries beginning with the letters "ab" for example?

Comment: yes use WHERE col_name LIKE 'ab%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason this won't worK?

SELECT * from TABLE WHERE col1 like 'ab%' or col2 like 'ab%' or....

Comment: That's what I was missing.. 'ab%' literally escaped my mind completely.  Let me give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

you should use like statement

```
select * from table where columnName like 'ab%'
```

Edit:
In your case this should solve your problem

```
select * from GardenType where GardenType.GardenType like 'ab%'
```

Comment: Tried several different variations of the code linked and it keeps returning the same error, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'".

Comment: could you please tell the tablename and columnname so that we can help.

Comment: Table name = GardenType, Column name = GardenType.  The table consists of only 3 columns which are GardenTypeID, GardenType, GardenDescription.

Comment: Are you using the same? select * from GardenType where GardenType.GardenType like 'ab%'

Comment: That sort of works, it's displaying the 3 columns but isn't showing any of the data.  One of the entries is "Relaxing" and doing select * from GardenType where GardenType.GardenType ='Re%' returns nothing :/

Comment: I edited the code. Replace "=" by "like"

Comment: Thanks man, worked perfectly. :D